# Word a pdf java

Tags: java, apache-poi

Estoy intentando convertir un doc a pdf

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try  {
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        document.createStyles();
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun title = paragraph.createRun();
        title.setText("gLETS GO");

        PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/pepe/Desktop/DocxToPdf1.pdf"));
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm getting error:

```
fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected end of file after null
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:71)
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:39)

Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected end of file
```

¿Alguna idea o otra forma de hacerlo?